# search "date :" in all sheets except sheet1 then paste the value to sheet1

Tags: excel, vba

Please kindly finish this code.

I would to search for the word "Date :" in all sheets(sheet2 to sheets...) and if found, copy the value to sheet1

Ex : if found the word "date :" in sheet2 column A1, then copy A2 value and paste to sheet1 column A1. copy and paste sheet3 to sheet1 column B1. process it in order

```
Sub help()
Dim SearchString As String
Dim SearchRange As Range, cl As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

    SearchString = "Date :"
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    Set ws = ws.Cells.Find(What:=SearchString, _
        After:=sh.Cells(1, 1), _
        LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, _
        SearchFormat:=False)
End Sub
```

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me know if this works for you

```
Sub help()
Dim SearchString As String
Dim cell As Range
Dim ws As Integer

    SearchString = "Date :"
    For ws = 2 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    UsedRng = Sheets(ws).UsedRange.Address
    For Each cell In Range(UsedRng).Cells
    If cell.Value = SearchString Then
        Sheets(1).Cells(1, ws - 1).Value = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
        Exit For
    End If

    Next

    Next

End Sub
```